# With docker is there a way of determining what images rely on another image

Tags: bash, docker

With `docker` I can identify all named and tagged containers with `docker images` which lists them out.

I can find out what other images a given image relies on using `docker inspect --format '{{.RootFS.Layers}}' _imageId_` and by manually comparing the SHA's I can see that image B utilises image A.

Is there any way I can get docker to tell me or use a bash (or portable shell) script that will find all named images that depend on a given image.  e.g. in this example B would be returned when I search for images depending upon A.

I have been unsuccessful searching the docker help output, online docker documentation, google and SE, SO, SU searches in finding an existing alternative to manually spotting the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the question, there appears to be no built in way to do this. The following [docker-find-dependants script is maintained here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RidiculousRichard/bash-dev-scripts/master/docker-find-dependants) and does the job

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to determine what named images and containers are dependent on the specified image (or a containers image) from stdin or in the args
# An unmatchable input is ignored
# All of the following will be found:
#    Any image name / tag / name:tag / id that has a prefix in it that matches the input
#    Any other image that relies on the images specified
#    Any containers (running or not) that use any of these images

set -euf -o pipefail

debugMsg() {
    true
    #printf "%s\n" "$@" >&2
}


specifiedParents=""
# Find all the images that need to be removed
if [ "$#" -ge "1" ]; then
    # Images for removal in args
    specifiedParents="$(printf " %s\n" "$@")"
else
    # Images for removal to arrive via stdin
    while IFS= read -r inStr; do
        if [ -n "$inStr" ]; then
            specifiedParents="$(printf "%s %s\n" "$specifiedParents" "$inStr")"
        fi
    done
fi
debugMsg "DBG:1 specifiedParents = '$specifiedParents'"

# Check there is some input
if [ -z "$specifiedParents" ]; then
    printf "%s" "Nothing specified to search for; images/containers must be specified as either args or on the stdin" >&2 
    exit 1
fi

# Collect the container and image info
containersData="$(docker ps -a --format 'Container {{.ID}} {{.Image}} {{.Names}} {{.Labels}}' --no-trunc)"
allImagesData="$(docker images -a --format 'Image {{.ID}} {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} {{.Repository}} {{.Tag}}' --no-trunc | sed 's/ [^:]*:/ /')"
namedImagesData="$(docker images --format 'Image {{.ID}} {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' --no-trunc | sed 's/ [^:]*:/ /')"
debugMsg "DBG:2 containersData = '$containersData'"
debugMsg "DBG:3 allImagesData = '$allImagesData'"
debugMsg "DBG:4 namedImagesData = '$namedImagesData'"

# Check to see if you can find a matching container
parents=""
while IFS= read -r aParent; do
    if [ -z "$aParent" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Use space to ensure matching starts at the beginning of a field
    anImageId=" $(printf "%s" "$containersData" | grep -F " $aParent" | awk '{print $3}' || true)"
    if [ "$anImageId" != " " ]; then
        # A container matched so use the image ID
        parents="$(printf "%s%s\n" "$parents" " $anImageId")"
    else
        # Not a container, so presumably an image
        parents="$(printf "%s%s\n" "$parents" " $aParent")"
    fi
done <<< $(printf "%s\n" "$specifiedParents") # Performing while inside this shell
#debugMsg "DBG:5 parents = '$parents'"

# Get the full parent image ID's
parentImageIds=""
while IFS= read -r aParent; do
    debugMsg "DBG:6 aParent = '$aParent'"
    # Find anything matching the parent and get it's full ID
    while IFS= read -r parentImageId; do
        if [ -z "$parentImageId" ]; then
            continue
        fi
        debugMsg "DBG:7 parentImageId = '$parentImageId'"
        # Add the full ID to the parentImageIds, including a space to assist matching later
        parentImageIds="$(printf "%s%s\n" "$parentImageIds" " $parentImageId")"
    done <<< $(printf "%s" "$allImagesData" | grep -F " $aParent" | awk '{print $2}')
done <<< $(printf "%s" "$parents") # Performing while inside this shell
debugMsg "DBG:8 parentImageIds = '$parentImageIds'"

# Stop if there are no parents
if [ -z "$parentImageIds" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# Deduplicate
parentImageIds="$(printf "%s" "$parentImageIds" | LC_ALL=C sort -u)"
debugMsg "DBG:9 parentImageIds = '$parentImageIds'"

# Find descendent images
descendentImages=""
while IFS= read -r imageData; do
    anImageId="$(printf "%s" "$imageData" | awk '{print $2}')"

    # Check to see if this ID is a descendent of parentImageIds by imageInfo by moving through it's lineage
    areDescendents=""
    imageIdsChecked=""
    while true; do
        # Record that anImageId is being checked; including the space at the start to assist matching later
        imageIdsChecked="$(printf "%s%s\n" "$imageIdsChecked" " $anImageId")"

        if printf "%s" "$descendentImages" | grep -q -F "$anImageId"; then
            # Already determined that anImageId is a descendent of parentImageIds so TheImage is too
            areDescendents="true"
            break;
        else
            if printf "%s" "$parentImageIds" | grep -q -F " $anImageId"; then
                # TheImage is a descendent of parentImageIds
                areDescendents="true"
                break;
            fi

            # Move onto the parent of anImageId
            anImageId="$(docker inspect --format '{{.Parent}}' "$anImageId" | sed 's/.*://')"
            if [ -z "$anImageId" ]; then
                # Reached the end of the line; abandon all hope ye who enter here
                break;
            fi
        fi
    done

    # Add descendents to the descendentImages
    if [ -n "$areDescendents" ]; then
        descendentImages="$(printf "%s%s\n" "$descendentImages" "$imageIdsChecked")"
    fi
done <<< $(printf "%s" "$allImagesData") # Performing while inside this shell
debugMsg "DBG:10 descendentImages = '$descendentImages'"

checkIfDescendentImageFound() {
    # Check to see if this is a descendent from any parent
    # $1 is thisImageId
    # $2 is the display text
    # Using the space to ensure matching form the start of an ID
    if printf "%s" "$descendentImages" | grep -q -F " $1"; then
        # We've found a descendent; display it quick before it gets away
        debugMsg "DBG: Found "
        printf "%s\n" "$2"
    fi
}

# Identify any named images that are descendents of the parentImageIds
debugMsg "DBG:11 namedImagesData = '$namedImagesData'"
printf "%s\n" "$namedImagesData" | while IFS= read -r imageData; do
    thisImageId="$(printf "%s" "$imageData" | awk '{print $2}')"
    checkIfDescendentImageFound "$thisImageId" "$imageData"
done

# Identify containers that rely on images that are descendents of the parentImageIds
debugMsg "DBG:12 containersData = '$containersData'"
printf "%s\n" "$containersData" | while IFS= read -r containerData; do
    thisImageId="$(printf "%s" "$containerData" | awk '{print $3}')"
    checkIfDescendentImageFound "$thisImageId" "$containerData"
done
```

Example:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f89b835ae7a0        96c117cf0a5e        "/bin/sleep infinity"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours                             test
$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                   IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
golang-build        2017-03-09T05-46GMT   96c117cf0a5e        39 hours ago        293 MB
<none>              <none>                752877a5f5b1        39 hours ago        293 MB
<none>              <none>                cb1c86494369        39 hours ago        3.98 MB
alpine              latest                4a415e366388        7 days ago          3.98 MB
$ docker-find-dependants blah
$ docker-find-dependants 752877a5f5b1
Image 96c117cf0a5ef75c6203f862ec92ae75418c1a431d86440dd71b945e5fdbff77 golang-build:2017-03-09T05-46GMT
Container f89b835ae7a08e0394c080d0e57de2020f6a9c6dd334bc078913171d4171962f 96c117cf0a5e test
```

Comment: If anyone has a more elegant answer than this script I would be interested in seeing it (and I'm sure others will too)

Comment: Note that while 'docker ps -f ancestor=xxxx' works, there is no ancestor filter for 'docker images'.  It should also be noted that by doing this operation in a script you can choose to order the images in a particular way.

Answer (score 1):

Not a *bash* solution - but for those that end up here simply looking to quickly eyeball dependencies for a **public** image - [contains.dev](https://contains.dev) is quite nice for visually exploring this info (image hierarchy, layers, files etc.).

For example - looking at the layers for the [continuumio/miniconda3:4.10.3p0](https://contains.dev/continuumio/miniconda3/4.10.3p0/layers) image, I can quickly see that it relies on the [debian:buster-20210721-slim](https://contains.dev/library/debian/buster-20210721-slim) image.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).